# What was the gate code for the mines, and did it have any significance?

Tags: jurassic-world-dominion

Near the end of *Jurassic World: Dominion*, when Grant and Sattler are trapped in the mines Ian Malcom has to guess the four-digit code to open the gates for them. The first few guesses he tries are all significant dates, which he states out loud and explains. The final, correct guess however is never either spoken or explained.

I wasn’t able to make out the buttons he pressed, but it looks like it should be possible. What was the code, and what does it mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's 7615, an Easter Egg to director Colin Trevorrow (born in 1976) and the first *Jurassic World* movie (released in 2015).

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Is there any evidence to suggest that this is the gate code?

Comment: nah no evidence got back from the cinema from that movie today maybe i remember wrong numbers but i think im right xD

Answer (score 0):

All that we can see Ian enter of the final code appears to be **969**, which is missing either the first, or last digit.
We then see Ramsay (in the control center) enter **9517** on his terminal, after which we see the gate unlock.
So the way I see it, Ian never actually guessed the code, and Ramsay simply remotely opened the gate for them.

Now as for what Ian might have tried, my guess is **1969**. It's the year of multiple things Ian might be interested in, such as the original Woodstock (his second guess was Miles Davis' birthday), the Apollo 11 moon landing, etc. But also, in *Jurassic Park 2*, Ian's car (the one they use to rescue the baby T-Rex in San Diego) is a 1969 Pontiac Custom S.

I don't know what would be the significance of the actual code (9517), and there simply might not be any, a reflection of how Ian was trying to use personally meaningful dates as codes, while in real life, such a gate's code would simply be something random.